# progressbar not reaching 100%

Tags: python, download, progress-bar

I'm trying to use the `progressbar` to show the download progress of a file.

My sample code :

```
r = browser.get(url, stream=True)
total_length = int(stream.headers.get('content-length'))
bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=(total_length/1024)).start()

with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
    i = 0
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        if chunk: 
            f.write(chunk)
            bar.update(i)
            i+=1
bar.finish()
```

This works fine for files over a size of few MBs but for files of few KBs, the download gets completed very quickly but the progress bar doesn't reach a 100%. It quits around 89-92%.

I tried introducing `time.sleep(0.1)` for each update which works but I don't think that is the correct way here.

Is it possible to make it reach a 100% even for small files ?

Comment: Do you close the progressbar when you are done loading the file? Because if you do keep in mind that the progressbar needs time to fill so your code is always a little further then what you see. So it gets closed before reaching 100%

Comment: @J.Goedhart yes, I do close the progressbar. But even without closing it, I'm not reachig 100% without using a delay.

Comment: When you shift from a dynamic progressbar to static it will update more acquired.

Comment: Today I am unable to reproduce this issue again. I didn't do any change on the code. My download speed is same and my progressbar reaches 100% even for 4kB file. I'm unable to find the reason.                                               @J.Goedhart I understand what we ar eusing here is dynamic progressbar. What do you mean by static ?

Comment: Most progresbars have two options: display dynamic or static. With dynamic you see the progresbar filling up. With static it just shifts x amount at the same time.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for clearing that up. I have resolved the issue. I forgot to factor in the correct content-length.